# Среда разработки для Go

Tags: golang, ide

Кто какую среду разработки может посоветовать для Go? 
Хотелось бы видеть в IDE:

1. Подсветку синтаксиса
2. Авто подстановку
3. Кросс платформенное решение
4. Автоматическую сборку кода

Как дополнение:

1. Работа через ssh

Comment: vim + Makefile ?

Answer (score 3):

[Goclipse](http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/)? Это кроссплатформенный плагин для Eclipse.

> **Features:**
>
> - Syntax highlighting
> - Automatic building of files
> - Run configuration support
> - ...

Answer (score 1):

Gedit как [среда](http://gohelp.wordpress.com/) для Go на Linux. Плюсы: бесплатно, легковесно, просто.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы превратить [Atom](https://atom.io/) в IDE для Go, достаточно установить два пакета и отладчик:

```
apm install go-plus go-debug
go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
```

- [`go-plus`](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus) — по сути, это "метапакет", он ничего сам по себе не делает, исключительно устанавливает следующее:

  - `autocomplete-go` занимается автодополнением
  - `gofmt` автоформатирует файлы при сохранении и чистит импорты
  - `builder-go` собирает пакет при каждом сохранении
  - `gometalinter-linter` анализирует код на проблемы целым набором инстументов
  - `navigator-godef` ищет определение выделенного идентификатора
  - `tester-go` отображает покрытие кода тестами
  - `gorename` переименовывает идентификатор по всему коду
- [`go-debug`](https://github.com/lloiser/go-debug) — удобная обёртка для отладчика [Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve), позволяющая ставить точки останова и осматривать состояние вдоль всего стека любой горутины.

  - Сам Delve, обычно, [прекрасно устанавливается с помощью `go get`](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/linux/install.md), при определённых условиях *даже в Windows*.

---

<sub>Я написал [пошаговую инструкцию по установке всего этого добра](http://dside.ru/go-setup/) на чистую Debian-подобную ОС и детали о том, как заставить это работать на Windows.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) + [Go плагин](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin). Плагин активно развивается, поддерживает перечисленные фичи (в том числе кроссплатформенность). Сразу можно и фронтенд разрабатывать в одной среде.

Answer (score 1):

IDE from JetBrains.  Пара плагинов и все работает прекрасно. При этом настройка легкая.

https://www.jetbrains.com/go/

Answer (score 1):

[GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/) от JetBrains ;) Так же рекомендую WebStorm, но мне GoLand больше нравится

Answer (score 0):

Vim + https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang

Answer (score 0):

http://go-ide.com/

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить VS Code, настроенную как написано по ссылке: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go

В итоге получаете:

- Подсветку синтаксиса
- Авто подстановку
- Кросс платформенное решение
- Автоматическую сборку кода
- Возможность отладки
- Авто импорт/удаление пакетов
- Интеграцию с Git и множество других полезных фич.

Уверен если поискать все эти плагины можно и на Vim поставить.